# Запустить PuTTY через PowerShell

Tags: powershell, putty

Я запустил putty через *PowerShell*:

`&'C:\test\dev.lnk'` - это точнее ссылка на дев сервер, открываемая через *putty*.

В открытом окне мне надо написать путь к скриптам: `cd script`.

Возможно ли как-то написать этот путь через *powershell*, а затем и запустить скрипты?

Т.е. как с помощью *PowerShell* мне писать что-либо в открытом ранее окне?

Comment: требуется решение именно именно на клиентской стороне?

Comment: Да, мне нужно сделать так, чтобы пауершелловский скрипт запустил PuTTY ввел путь к сриптам, а потом уже ввел сами скрипты. Всё это я делаю вручную, но запускать сотни скриптов каждый раз - дело очень долгое.
Прошу извинить, если как-то не так объяснил.

Comment: возможно, проще будет автоматизировать запуск «сотен скриптов» на стороне сервера. их всего лишь надо будет записать в файл — по одной команде в строке —  и передать файл первым аргументом программе `bash`.

Comment: а вот на этого «[монстра](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Sample-PowerShell-module-8d961a1c)» не смотрели?

Comment: К сожалению, я полный гуманитарий, поэтому надеялся, что можно сделать вот так всё просто. Попытаюсь разобраться, как сделать это через bash или модуль, но вряд ли к меня получится. 
Спасибо за Ваши ответы:)

Answer (score 2):

для автоматизации выполнения фиксированного набора команд в unix-подобных операционных системах можете поступить так:

1. впишите все команды в файл с произвольным именем (в именах файлов лучше избегать пробелов и других спец-символов, ограничьтесь латинскими буквами в нижнем регистре, арабскими цифрами, точкой, минусом и знаком подчёркивания) — по одной команде на строку:

   ```
   команда1
   команда2
   команда3
   ```
2. поместите этот файл в каталог, например, `/usr/local/bin/`: обычно он перечислен в переменной окружения `PATH`, поэтому помещённые в него файлы можно запускать откуда угодно по их именам.
3. присвойте файлу бит исполнимости:

   ```
   chmod +x /usr/local/bin/moj.nabor.comand.nomer.raz
   ```
4. запускайте этот файл по имени:

   ```
   moj.nabor.komand.nomer.raz
   ```

---

**оговорка**

если у вас нет прав для записи в каталог `/usr/local/bin/`, поместите файл в свой домашний каталог, и сразу после логина запускайте его так:

```
sh moj.nabor.komand.nomer.raz
```

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант, можно использовать связку из **pscp**, чтобы положить скрипты на сервер, затем **plink**, чтобы выполнить на сервере команду. Но в таком случае мне не очень понятен смысл использования PowerShell - вполне можно обойтись банальным BATCH скриптом. Обе утилиты идут в комплекте с [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html).

Пример скрипта на PowerShell с использованием pscp и plink:

```
$PuTTYPath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY"
$User = 'administrator'
$Pass = Read-Host 'Password' -AsSecureString | ConvertFrom-SecureString
$HostName = 'ubuntu-test'

# Кладём скрипт на сервер; обязательно с флагом -Wait, чтобы скрипт дождался загрузки файлов
Start-Process -FilePath "$PuTTYPath\pscp.exe" `
-ArgumentList "-pw $Pass D:\Soft\Ubuntu\*.sh $User@$HostName`:/home/administrator" -Wait

# Запускаем скрипты (предполагаем, что нам не важен порядок запуска)
Start-Process -FilePath "$PuTTYPath\plink.exe" `
-ArgumentList "-ssh -pw $Pass $User@$HostName cd /home/administrator/ && chmod +x *.sh && ./*.sh"
```